# Java Detect MouseClick anywhere in Window doesn't work in certain areas

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouseevent, mouselistener

So I have a Java Swing program and I want to be able detect mouse clicks.

```
addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        update(evt); //another method in the program
    }
});
```

The code works if I click on the window's side or places where there isn't an object, but does not work when I click on objects in the JFrame, such as my JTable or my text field.

Please help me how to have the MouseListener work on objects inside the JFrame as well.

Comment: What is the point of the `MouseListener`, what does it do?

Comment: `MouseListener` detects mouse events like mouse movement and mouse clicks.

Comment: @Brandon Nguyen, I'm new to New to GUI in java, but I would imagine the components in the JFrame, such as your textbox etc need to also have the same mouse listener calling the method *update(evt)*. I can't imagine that not working, but I really don't know for sure as I don't have time to test. There may be an easier way that I am unaware of, so I hope you get a good answer.

Comment: @nixxbb Yeah, but that would be such a pain to add the Listener to every single object.

Comment: I know, I hope you get a good answer. If I have time to play with it later I will check back...

Comment: `<head-desk />`  I know what a `MouseListener` does, but *why* does the app. need to detect those movements and clicks?

Answer (score 1):

When you click on a textfield, the textfield gains focus. That means your frame loses ownership of focus, and since your listener is most likely added to your frame, your listener stops working right when frame isnt in focus. Add your listener to all compoments, or use Key Binding

Comment: Oh so that explains why. Thanks. I'll have to add more listeners then.